# Add event to xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I add a property `Name` or `x:Name` to this XAML code(in combobox):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding name_ru}" Width="Auto" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle}" SelectionChanged="status_SelectionChanged" Height="auto" Width="Auto">
                 <ComboBox.BorderBrush>
                     <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource Color1}"/>
                 </ComboBox.BorderBrush>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

and how added event `Click` or other in this XAML code:

```
<!--Clien-->
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Client name" HeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding user_name}"  Width="Auto" Height="Auto" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<!--end Clien-->
```

My top xaml:

```
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Classic"
       xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
        xmlns:ee="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/effects"
         xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
          mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="JanPizza.IndexFormPizza"
    x:Name="MainWnd"
    Title="MainWindow"
    MouseLeftButtonDown="MainWnd_MouseLeftButtonDown"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
    xmlns:wpftoolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    xmlns:filter="clr-namespace:DataGridFilterLibrary;assembly=DataGridFilterLibrary"    

    Width="1065" Height="674" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="5" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Foreground="#FF2D2D2D" Icon="wnd-icon.png" Style="{DynamicResource WindowStyle}" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" AllowDrop="False">
```

Comment: what is the problem? `<ComboBox Name="status" ....`

Comment: please provide top of your xaml file

Answer (score 0):

Just use the properties:

```
<ComboBox Name="myCombobox" ... /> <TextBlock MouseLeftButtonDown="textblock_mouseLeftButtonDown" ... />
```

Comment: It's not wrong, you can add a name, just you won't be able to refer to it, because it is in a template.

Comment: if i set name, then here not visible in code, i need visible in code

Comment: If you use templates, you should use data binding, and commands to interact with your controls.
However, you can find a control by name with this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx